# Loading posts associated only to the logged in user on recent posts page

Tags: plugins, users, content-restriction

Dear Wordpress Captains,

I've stumbled upon a problem and I am seeking for assistance.

What I'm trying to create is a customer portal where the logged in user will only see the posts that are associated to their username. It would be great if this could work on the recent posts page (or index.. The page that a user gets to see first when they logged in, with all the recent posts). I don't have any static pages, besides a contact page (in case this matters).

It seems like a very easy fix, but I have tried every single plugin that I managed to find. For example, one of the plugins I've tried in 'User Specific Content' - but this isn't exactly what I'm looking for as it blocks off the content only when clicked on the post (to open the actual post).. What I'm looking for is a way to already only show the accessible posts for the logged in user on the main page.

There's only one author - the admin, and there's many users (customers, set as subscribers) who are meant to only see the individual posts allocated to their individual username. What's the easiest way to do this? Perhaps I could only query the posts that are in the category of the user? (I've posted each post in the category named after the customer).
I hope that this clarifies my problem and what I'm trying to achieve.

Please do not hesitate to ask for more information if it isn't quite clear enough!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Aravona Not quite, I'm not trying to eliminate a certain element of the post for a user.. What I'm trying to achieve is for posts that are not 'linked' with the logged in user to not show up at all. Is there any way possible to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to get the current logged in user ID and then use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query on the home/blog page to only show posts from that specific user. As I understand, you are talking specifically about authors.

You might want to also check the user's capabilities as well as simple subscribers won't see any posts on the blog/homepage as they can't author posts.

A very simple `pre_get_posts` action will look something like this: (***NOTE:*** The following is untested)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{    
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { // First check if we have a logged in user before doing anything
        if (    $q->is_home() // Only targets the main page, home page
             && $q->is_main_query() // Only targets the main query
        ) {
            // Get the current logged in user
            $current_logged_in_user = wp_get_current_user();

            // Set the logged in user ID as value to the author parameter
            $q->set( 'author', $current_logged_in_user->ID );
        }
    }    
});
```

### EDIT

From comments, it seems that each user has a category with the same name and this specific category is then attached to a post

To accommodate this, you will need to do the following

- As above, get the current logged in user
- You will then need to use the info from the current user which will match up to the category. For instance and as an example, if `'display_name' == 'category name'`, then, if the user display name is `Jane Doe`, then the category name assigned to the name will also be called `Jane Doe`
- In the above example, we need to get the category by name so that we can get the category ID. We will be using `get_term_by()` which can be used with build in taxonomies like `category` or custom taxonomies
- We can then go ahead and do the same as in the original answer

You can do something like this; (*I have commented the code so you can understand and follow it better*)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{    
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { // First check if we have a logged in user before doing anything
        if (    $q->is_home() // Only targets the main page, home page
             && $q->is_main_query() // Only targets the main query
        ) {
            // Get the current logged in user
            $current_logged_in_user = wp_get_current_user();
            /**
             * We will now get the term/category object from the user display_name
             * You will need to make sure if this corresponds with your term/category
             * If not, use the correct info to match
             */
            $term = get_term_by( 
                'name', // We will get our term by name as term name == user display_name. Change as needed
                $current_logged_in_user->display_name, // Our value to look for will be user display_name
                'category' // The taxonomy the term belongs to. category is the build in taxonomy
            );
            if ( $term ) { // Only filter the main query if we actually have a term with the desired name
                $q->set( 'cat', $term->term_id ); // Filter the posts to only show posts from the desired category
            }
        }
    }    
});
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the reply. I'm actually not talking about authors. There's only one author - the admin, and there's many users (customers, set as subscribers) who are meant to only see the individual posts allocated to their individual username. What's the easiest way to do this? Perhaps I could only query the posts that are in the category of the user? (I've posted each post in the category named after the customer). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please update your question properly and add **all** relevant info inside the question. If you want an exact answer, please provide correct details :-)

Comment: See my update. I do not know your exact setup, so please make double sure that you match your exact setup to the code

Comment: Any feedback on this issue?

Comment: Hello Pieter! My apologies for the late response, I haven't been able to work on this yet. It seems very well structured and I'd very much like to implement this right now. However, I'm going to be honest with you.. I'm quite new to Wordpress. So I'm assuming I'm adding this code to index.php, but where exactly? Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, just curious I guess :-). This goes into functions.php (or even a custom plugin :-))

Comment: I'm getting this currently.. I've checked, and it's within the additional code.. Do you perhaps know a fix for this? `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /wp-content/themes/ink/functions.php on line 277`

Comment: Sorry, I did not test the code, but there were two syntax errors which I've spotted. I have updated both code snippets and should in theory work

Comment: Hello Pieter, thanks again. However, I've got two users with their own category that contains posts (the first has many, the other only one). The second user seems to be working fine, as it only shows the posts from the right category (besides the 'next & previous posts' on the bottom of the post page, posts from the other category do still show here). But with the first user, the post from the other category is still showing.. Even though it's just one. Would this be easy to fix?

Comment: You should make sure that your user display name is exactly the same as the category name. If it is not, it will mean that the category does not exist, which in turn will fail on the filter which will show all posts for the mismatch. As I said, I do not know your exact setup, you need to match up to that yourself.

Comment: Pieter, after adding more posts to the new category it successfully worked (don't ask me why, haha). I'll play around with this for some time. Thank you so much for helping me out with the code. Is there any way that I can help you out in return? Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked out. You should definitely play around with some ideas to fine tune this to make it more reliable and less error prone. My answer is just a basic idea ;-). Enjoy